# Как вывести данные за определенный промежуток времени

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры, вектор

Предположим, имеется массив структур:

```
struct orders {
    int cost;
    int dayOfIssue;
    int monthOfIssue;
    int yearOfIssue;
};
    vector <orders> Ord;
```

В массиве структур содержится цена и дата появления товара на складе. Как посчитать прибыль за введенный пользователем промежуток времени. Планировал сделать это также, как и при проверке, появился ли товар до введенного срока, т.е

```
int curDay, curMonth, curYear;
    cout << "Enter the today's day" << endl;
    cin >> curDay;
    cout << "Enter the month" << endl;
    cin >> curMonth;
    cout << "Enter the year" << endl;
    cin >> curYear;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Ord.size(); i++) {
        if (curYear > Ord[i].yearOfIssue || (curYear == Ord[i].yearOfIssue && curMonth > Ord[i].monthOfIssue) || (curYear == Ord[i].yearOfIssue && curMonth == Ord[i].monthOfIssue && curDay > Ord[i].dayOfIssue)) {
            indexesOverdued.push_back(i);
        }
}
```

Но пришел к выводу, что придется расписывать слишком много случаев. Возможно ли это как-то оптимизировать?

Comment: Переводите даты в секунды от epoch

Comment: по цене товара невозможно определить прибыль склада...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно - если уж это С++ - использовать `tie`:

```
if (std::tie(curYear,curMonth,curDay) > 
    std::tie(Ord[i].yearOfIssue,Ord[i].monthOfIssue,Ord[i].dayOfIssue)) ...
```

Comment: так не получится.  Если годы и месяцы  одинаковы,  а дни разные, что тогда?..

Comment: Все в порядке - смотрите: https://ideone.com/dhkXZe

Comment: да, есть вариант, что я ошибся

Answer (score 3):

Переводите поля даты в одно число. Для реальных дат вполне годится

```
date = year*10000 + month*100 + day
```

А уж такие даты в виде одного числа сравниваются легким движением клавиатуры :)

Comment: Для данного кода  лучше не придумаешь

Comment: Можно сразу хранить дату в таком виде в структуре. Или для скорости - в упакованном наподобие `date = year << 9 + month << 5 + day` - так должно работать быстрее, чем умножения и деления на степени 10.

Comment: Harry,спасибо. Но не совсем понимаю, зачем год на 10000 умножать. Ведь по сути, при адекватном вводе данных (т.е не 1 год условно, а 2018), год и так будет намного больше, чем месяц или день. Поэтому предлагаю  date = year + month*10 + day, т.к день может быть больше чем месяц

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii Намного - это насколько? 2058 - это что? 20.02.2018 или 10.03.2018 или 19.03.2019 или что? В моем варианте это, понятно, только для того, чтоб **человеку** было легче воспринимать. Достаточно месяц умножать на 32, а год - на 416. Отлаживать только тяжелее :)

Comment: @Harry, понял. Не учел этот случай